# How to use Paypal IPN notification and notify_url in the same form?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I am using such paypal form(the payment is ok) for subscription plan and don't get any IPN notifications, but when I use standart paypal forms generated by paypal everything with IPN notification is ok. Is there a way to get IPN with this form? Thanks

Here is my form. I can get the data only on notify_url or by IPM if I remove the notify_url from this form.

**PS> The main question! Is there a way to use both ipn + notify_url? Example?**

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/a-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">

        <!-- Identify your business so that you can collect the payments. -->
        <input type="hidden" name="business" value="info@****.***">

        <!-- Specify a Buy Now button. -->
        <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick-subscriptions">

        <!-- Specify details about the item that buyers will purchase. -->
        <table>
            <tbody><tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="hidden" name="on1" value="Mobile/Cell Phone number:"><strong>Mobile/Cell Phone number:</strong>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" maxlength="200" name="os1" required="">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input id="item_name" type="hidden" name="item_name" value="kp4">
                    <input id="item_number" type="hidden" name="item_number" value="1">
                    <label>Subscription Plans</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <!-- <input type="hidden" name="a3" value="5.00"> -->
                    <input data-name="kp4" data-id="1" type="radio" name="a3" value="0.01" checked=""> 0,01 /month <br>
                    <input data-name="kp5" data-id="2" type="radio" name="a3" value="0.02"> 0,01 /month <br>
                    <input data-name="kp6" data-id="3" type="radio" name="a3" value="0.03">0,01 /month <br>
                    <input data-name="kp7" data-id="4" type="radio" name="a3" value="0.04> 0,01 /month <br>
                    <input data-name="kp8+" data-id="5" type="radio" name="a3" value="0.05"> 0,05 /month <br>
                    <input type="hidden" name="p3" value="1"> 

                    <input type="hidden" name="t3" value="M">
                    <input type="hidden" name="src" value="1">
                    <input type="hidden" name="sra" value="1">
                    <input type="hidden" name="custom" value="ORG">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody></table>
        <!-- Specify Currency Code -->
        <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
        <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">
        <input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2">

        <!-- Specify URLs -->
        <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="***payment-success.php?site_name=ORG">
        <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="****payment-cancel.php">
        <input type="hidden" name="return" value="***payment-success.php">

        <input type="image" name="submit" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_subscribeCC_LG.gif" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online">
        <img alt="" border="0" width="1" height="1" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif">
    </form>
```

Comment: Have you check your IPN history? I afraid you have a custom notify URL but only one listener.

Comment: @AnaheimElectronics Thanks for the answer. But what do you mean by " only one listener"? As I understand my  notify IPN URL is using for every notification in paypal account. Where can I read about the listeners? And I can see in history that my missed notifications were send by paypal but I didn't see them in my dump, but the others are there. I am using 3 websites with one paypal account and one notification URL for IPN. But don't see my test IPN payments for 0.01$

Comment: Your `notify_url` needs to accept a POST with a long list of IPN variables, and not fail in processing them. It doesn't make much if any sense to use the same page for both `return` and `notify_url`. But you can certainly use a dynamic `notify_url`: I've been doing it for years.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> PS> The main question! Is there a way to use both ipn + notify_url?
>   Example?

In short: **No**

But can your desired results be achieved? **Yes**

This has been something haunting Paypal for years and still does.

There is a very popular method (for those who know) to get around this using php and curl and is distributed by Codeseekah. (Not affiliated)

> **The concept**
>
> An single IPN URL is setup for PayPal to notify your application of
>   payments. The IPN handler code broadcasts PayPal’s payload to other
>   IPN URLs you may have selectively or in bulk.
>
> - multiple PayPal IPN URLs now possible
> - no need to change any IPN code unless it filters requests by IP
> - can centralize IP filtering into the broadcast IPN, which means easier to maintain when PayPal’s IP ranges change
> - can centralize logging
> - can have queuing and rebroadcast if satellites (all your other IPN URLs) are unreachable

---

**The Code**

This IPN broadcast code is in PHP, but the concept is non-language specific. Simply port the code and it will do equally well or even better.

```
<?php
  /*
   * This is a PayPal IPN (Instant Payment Notification) broadcaster
   * Since PayPal does not provide any straightforward way to add
   * multiple IPN listeners we'll have to create a central IPN
   * listener that will broadcast (or filter and dispatch) Instant
   * Payment Notifications to different destinations (IPN listeners)
   *
   * Destination IPN listeners must not panic and recognize IPNs sent
   * by this central broadcast as valid ones in terms of source IP
   * and any other fingerprints. Any IP filtering must add this host,
   * other adjustments made as necessary.
   *
   * IPNs are logged into files for debugging and maintenance purposes
   *
   * this code comes with absolutely no warranty
   * https://codeseekah.com
  */

  ini_set( 'max_execution_time', 0 ); /* Do not abort with timeouts */
  ini_set( 'display_errors', 'Off' ); /* Do not display any errors to anyone */
  $urls = array(); /* The broadcast session queue */

  /* List of IPN listener points */
  $ipns = array(
      'mystore' => 'http://mystore.com/ipn.php',
      'myotherstore' => 'http://mybigstore.com/paypal_ipn.php',
      'myotherandbetterstore' => 'http://slickstore.com/paypal/ipn.php'
    );

  /* Fingerprints */

  if ( /* My Store IPN Fingerprint */
    preg_match( '#^\d+\|[a-f0-9]{32}$#', $_POST['custom'] ) /* Custom hash */
    and $_POST['num_cart_items'] == 2 /* alwayst 1 item in cart */
    and strpos( $_POST['item_name1'], 'MySite.com Product' ) == 0 /* First item name */
  ) $urls []= $ipns['mystore']; /* Choose this IPN URL if all conditions have been met */

  if ( /* My Other Store IPN Fingerprint */
    sizeof( explode('_', $_POST['custom']) ) == 7 /* has 7 custom pieces */
  ) $urls []= $ipns['myotherstore']; /* Choose this IPN URL if all conditions have been met */

  /* My Other And Better Store IPN Fingerprint */
  $custom = explode('|', $_POST['custom']);
  if (
    isset($custom[2]) and $custom[2] == 'FROM_OB_STORE' /* custom prefixes */
  ) $urls []= $ipns['myotherandbetterstore']; /* Choose this IPN URL if all conditions have been met */

  /* ... */


  /* Broadcast */

  if ( !sizeof($urls) ) $urls = $ipns; /* No URLs have been matched */
  $urls = array_unique( $urls ); /* Unique, just in case */

  /* Broadcast (excluding IPNs from the list according to filter is possible */
  foreach ( $urls as $url ) broadcast( $url );

  header( 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK', true, 200 );
  exit(); /* Thank you, bye */

  /* Perform a simple cURL-powered proxy request to broadcast */
  function broadcast( $url ) {

    /* Format POST data accordingly */
    $data = array();
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) $data []= urlencode($key).'='.urlencode($value);
    $data = implode('&', $data);

    /* Log the broadcast */
    file_put_contents('_logs/'.time().'.'.reverse_lookup( $url ).'-'.rand(1,100), $data);

    $ch = curl_init(); /* Initialize */

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($data));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    curl_exec($ch); /* Execute HTTP request */

    curl_close($ch); /* Close */
  }

  function reverse_lookup( $url ) {
    global $ipns;
    foreach ( $ipns as $tag => $_url ) {
      if ( $url == $_url ) return $tag;
    }
    return 'unknown';
  }
?>
```

The full article is at https://codeseekah.com/2012/02/11/how-to-setup-multiple-ipn-receivers-in-paypal/

**Note:** the author is very active and replies to all questions.